# Every cycling number is a repetend of a recurring decimal?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

There are several (and sometimes controversial) definitions of a cyclic number. I take the easiest to deal with:

*n-digit number is cyclic if its products by $2,\,3\dots (n-1)$ are cyclic permutations of the original number*

The best-known cyclic number is $142857=\frac{10^6-1}{7}$
$$
\begin{array}\\
142857 \times 2 = 285714\; &\;  142857 \times 3 = 428571\; &\; 142857 \times 4 = 571428 \\
142857 \times 5 = 714285\; &\;  142857 \times 6 = 857142 
\end{array}
$$

Another one is $0588235294117647 = \frac{10^{16}-1}{17}$ (Unfortunately, zero at start cannot be omitted)

---

I can prove that if $p$ is a full-repetend prime (i.e. the repetend of $\frac{1}{p}$ consists of $p-1$ digits) then $\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{p}$ (Fermat quotient) is a cyclic number. In other words, if $p$ is a full-repetend prime, then the repetend of $\frac{1}{p}$ is a cycling number.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number) claims also the opposite: *Any cyclic number can be represented as a Fermat quotient of a full-repetend prime*. (Any cycling number is a repetend of $\frac{1}{p}$ for some full-repetend $p$). Quite obviously it's sufficient to demonstrate that $a(n+1)=10^n-1$, for $n$-or-less-digit cycling number $a$.  Any idea of proving that?

Comment: I can't find that quoted sentence in Wikipedia.

Comment: lhf. "Relation to repeating decimals... A cyclic number of length $L$ is the digital representation of $\frac{1}{L+1}$."  Not quite strictly formulated, but in essence that's it.

Comment: lhf Further on: "Form of cycling numbers.. From the relation to unit fractions, it can be shown that cyclic numbers are of the form of the Fermat quotient $\frac{b^{p-1}-1}{p}$ where b is the number base (10 for decimal), and p is a prime that does not divide b. (Primes p that give cyclic numbers in base b are called full reptend primes or long primes in base b)"